# Why is my media query not working for big resolution?

Tags: html, css

I would like to program a web that has 3 columns in a PC and a single column in a smartphone. The problem is that the class "item" inside my media query doesn't seem to work. Somehow the main "item" is always working even though I use a PC, showing two columns instead of three.
This is the HTML code:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  margin-left: 32px;
  margin-right: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  width: 311px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 565px;
  top: 624px;
  background: #C15D5D;
  box-shadow: 3px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.item.green {
  background-color: #71B083;
}

.item.yellow {
  background-color: #D2BB68;
}

@media (min-width: 1281px) {
  .item {
    border-style: solid;
    flex: 0 32%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    /* (100-32*3)/2 */
    width: 311px;
    height: 200px;
    left: 565px;
    top: 624px;
    background: #C15D5D;
    box-shadow: 3px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
  .item.green {
    background-color: #71B083;
    left: 212px;
  }
  .item.yellow {
    background-color: #D2BB68;
    left: 918px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item green">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item yellow">3</div>
    <div class="item green">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item yellow">6</div>
    <div class="item green">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item yellow">9</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The width of the elements is 32%. The margin on each side is 32px;

To have three elements side-by-side you need to fit 192px of margin into the 4% of space that is left over.

For that to happen, the content width of the container needs to be 4608px, so the window would need to be much wider than 1281px.

Comment: Well, it's mobile first design so the code before the media query works great for phone (in phone I just want one column). If I use the same code I have inside the media query on the mobile class "item", I can see three columns. So, the code inside the media query works. Idk why the media query doesnt react.